# flutter: fill remain space of screen with listview

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have this widget tree:

```
Scaffold
  AppBar
  Column
    Center
    SingleChildScrollView
    FutureBuilder
       Container
       Flex
          direction: Axis.vertical,
          children: <Widget>[
          Row(),
          .....
          UserCommentsWidget(id)
          ]
```

In `UserCommentsWidget` i am using a future builder to load data from web service and show a list view :

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<UserCommentModel>(
      future: _userCommentsFuture,
      builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        } else if (!snapshot.hasError && snapshot.hasData) {
          return snapshot.data.data.list.length != 0
              ? Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(),  
                    Container(
                    ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.list.length,
                        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                          return 
                           commentItems(snapshot.data.data.list[index]);
                        }),
                     )
                  ],
                )
```

But i got this error :

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#c406c relayoutBoundary=up15 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1694 pos 12: 'hasSize'
```

I put **Listview** into **Expanded** but i got same error, How can i fill remain space with listview ?

Comment: why do you have `SingleChildScrollView`? Please share the complete code so I can find the issue.

Comment: This is full ui code https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ysy6XHjSVs/ @SanjaySharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my widget tree to this:

```
Scaffold
  AppBar
  Column
    Expanded
      FutureBuilder
       Container
       Column
          children: <Widget>[
          Row(),
          .....
          Expanded
             UserCommentsWidget(id)
          ]
```

and now everything is ok .Thanks all guys

Answer (score 0):

Flex and Expanded can help you in this case.

```
Flex(
direction: Axis.vertical,
children: <Widget>[
Expanded(child: ListView.builder(//IMPLEMENT YOUR LIST//))
])
```

Answer (score -1):

Put `ListView.builder` inside Expanded so that it will fill the space.

Comment: I got this error https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Dp32jRMhRN/ @KumarSunil17

Comment: Can you share the updated code, in which you places Expanded then ListView?